# Integrals using Cauchy integration formula

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

> Determine, using Cauchy Integral formula, the value of $\int_{0}^{2 \pi}\frac{1}{2+\sin\theta}d\theta$

Progress;

Substitute $z=e^{i\theta}$ and use that $\sin\theta=\frac{1}{2i}(z+\frac{1}{z})$
and $d \theta=\frac{1}{i}\frac{dz}{z}$.

Hence $2+\sin\theta=2+\frac{1}{2i}(z+\frac{1}{z})=\frac{1}{2}(4-iz+\frac{i}{z})$ and $\frac{d\theta}{2+\sin\theta}=\frac{2dz}{z^2+4iz-1}$. If I complete the square I see that ${z^2+4iz-1}=(z-i(\sqrt{3}-2))(z+i(\sqrt{3}+2)$. Denote the roots by $z_0$ and $z_1$ and we see that $z_0$ lies within $\left | z \right |=1$ and $z_1$ lies outside $\left | z \right |=1$. Correct so far?

Now I want to use CIF: I'll take the "largest" function which is $f(z)=\frac{1}{z+q}$ which is holomorphic on the disc $\left | z \right |<\sqrt{3}+2$. But how do I use CIF here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the change of variables transforms the interval $[0,2\pi]$ to the unit circle $|z|=1$. Hence
$$
\int_{|z|=1} \frac{2\,dz}{z^2+4iz-1} =
\int_{|z|=1} \frac{\frac{2}{z+i(\sqrt3 + 2)}}{z-i(\sqrt 3 -2)} \, dz=
2\pi i \cdot \frac{2}{i(\sqrt 3 -2)+i(\sqrt3 + 2)} = \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt 3}
$$
where we are using Cauchy's integral theorem on $f(z) = \dfrac{2}{z+i(\sqrt3 + 2)}$ which is holomorphic on (a neighbourhood) of the unit disc.

Comment: There is one step I don't follow. Why does this hold: $$\int_{|z=1|} \frac{\frac{2}{z+i(\sqrt3 + 2)}}{z-i(\sqrt 3 -2)} \, dz=
2\pi i \cdot \frac{2}{i(\sqrt 3 -2)+i(\sqrt3 + 2)}$$

Comment: @EricAm $$\int_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z-a}\,dz = 2\pi i f(a).$$Here $a=i(\sqrt 3 -2)$ and $$f(z) = \frac{2}{z+i(\sqrt 3+2)}$$